# Physics updates different with different fps

Tags: java, android, libgdx, game-physics, desktop

Before adding the `detune` variable, the physics update on a computer and a smartphone was strikingly different.
After adding and multiplying some variables, it turned out to smooth out the difference, but not make it completely the same.
In this regard, I ask for help, because I cannot figure out what to do myself.

```
public void update(float dt, Camera cam){
    float detune=dt/0.01666f;
    if(!ignoreGraviry)
        attraction.add(getGravity().cpy().scl(detune));
    float lx=1-.09f*detune;
    float ly=1-.015f*detune;
    attraction.scl(lx,ly);
    Vector v=getMotion().scl(lx,ly).cpy();
    lastPos=getPosition().cpy();
    getPosition().add(
        v.rotate(cam.getRotation()).add(
            attraction.cpy().rotate(cam.getRotation())
        ).scl(dt));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

What `detune` does is to scale up simulation cycle effects by a factor of 60. So basically, instead of having to simulate 60 cycles, this only has to simulate 1 cycle. But the results will be more inaccurate, maybe only a bit, maybe a lot, depending on if the rest of the simulation outside is stable/converging or not. Also with `lx` and `ly`, the way this `detune` is done LOOKS awfully bad (it MIGHT be OK with some outside knowlegde that your question does not provide), because you should never combine linear scaling effects with addition. This will throw you into hell's pit faster than you can imagine. `lx` for example will take negative numbers or positive, depending on `dt`. `dt` usually is the 'delta time' and lets you adjust the granularity vs speed of the simulation. So if someone adjusts `dt` and all of a sudden the simulation runs backwards, this will become a real sore issue.

## Solution

You should NOT have `detune` in your code like this. Better increase the `dt` value. Ensure that calculation cycles have the same temporal distance on PC and Smartphones, like 30 times a second (30 fps, dt=33ms) and sleep the rest of the time. If you cannot guarantee that, simulation results will always differ between them, bringing advantages or disadvantages to either.

I do not know if *libgdx* has a fixed simulation-graphics-cycle, so exactly one simulation per graphics update. But in most engines (yes, especially games, that's why multithread/-core is usually useless there) they are heavily coupled, which - in modern programming languages - is really bad because then you'd have to restrict your simulation algorithm AND graphics updates to the lowest hardware for BOTH PCs AND phones, AND restricting them to both the worst graphical AND computational minimum requirements.

*If* you can decouple simulation and graphics, you'd only have to consider the lowest computational capabilities. Concerning graphics, you could always run the max frame rate on each system (or limit to 90fps, only very few people have a higher acuity), making the best of the graphics hardware, getting the smoothest rendering.